# Splitting a word in jquery with space as the user is typing

Tags: jquery

I am trying to Check the textfield automatically as the user is typing and split a word into 2 words with a space, for example when users type a zip code, like 12345, i want to automatically add a space after the third digit, like 123 45, but i don't know of any function s that can do this.

I am checking the field with onupdate and onkeydown since i also want it to work when pasting.

Comment: Please show your attempt so far

Comment: [jQuery.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)?

Comment: why do you need to do this? Cant you format after submission and then show the user the formatted version if they need to see it. All you will achieve with this method is annoying people.

Comment: Agreed with @DavidB.  This is not a usable solution.  You should format it after the user has finished interacting with the field.

Comment: Please do not question what i'm trying to do as you do not know what i will use it for nor how it will work, or how i need it to be. I came here looking for help with code not criticism on what i'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Just trying to help you pal, there was no criticism. Try and be a little less sensitive, I obviously have more experience than you, see it as a positive rather than a negative.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/9CAGT/

```
$('#input').on('keyup',function(e) {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if(value.length == 3) {
       $(this).val(value + " ");   
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks! is there any way to have it work when pasting 5 numbers too though?

Answer (score 2):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/sg5kv/)***

Here is a simple example of detecting user input and placing a space after 3 in 1234. It will need to be modified to match your logic though.

```
$("#i").bind("input",function(){
 if( this.value.length > 3 ){
  var v = this.value;
  if( v[3] == " " ) return;
  this.value = v.substr(0,3) + " " + v.substr(3);
 }
});
```

Comment: works great except it changes the position of the last 2 digits you type

Comment: @SimonAndersson - As in from 12345 to 123 45? I thought that was what you were after. Feel free to change the logic inside of the callback function to suite your needs :)

Comment: No, as in when you type and get to the space 4 and 5 switches position
like 123 54 (at least when i type)

Comment: @SimonAndersson - I am unable to reproduce that. I see 123 45 when I type. I had a few other users test as well.

Comment: very strange, this is what it looks like for me
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-wx8xqYLzzg

Comment: @Simon - Interesting. It looks like the cursor moves to the previous spot instead of to the end in your browser (Safari?). Sorry, I am not sure what you would need to do in order to change the cursor position in the input. Technically it is in order, it is just that the cursor gets placed in the wrong spot. Does this version prevent the cursor from being moved before the 4? http://jsfiddle.net/sg5kv/1/ is in order

Answer (score 0):

Ended up going with the http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/ plugin, but thanks everybody ^_^